# unable to upgrade node js latest version

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to upgrade the node latest version not working but npm is upgraded to latest version and I don't have admin access.

I'm getting following error, When use this comment `npm install node@latest`

[image]

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Des
ktop\foldername\package.json'

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Deskto
p\react\package.json'

npm WARN react No description

npm WARN react No repository field.

npm WARN react No README data

npm WARN react No license field.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-g` flag to your command to specify that it is a global install.

Comment: Can you share some screenshots ?

Comment: Do you also have a local version of node installed ?